# Can't Retrieve Text Data Posted By Form Tag in Express JS

Tags: javascript, html, express, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple pipeline that when a user highlights a text block in the chrome page and click the extension, it shows the highlighted text inside the `<iframe>` defined in `popup.js` of chrome extension and send the text highlighted to the server running in `Express.js`.

The current status is popup.html running the popup.js and popup.js writes down `highlighted text` into `document`. So far, it works well.

However, the running terminal of `node app.js` keep showing `undefined` whenever I hit the `chrome extension favicon`. I expects the highlighted text shown up in the terminal log.

What would be the possible reason for this wrongful action?

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            body {
                width: 400px;
                height: 500px;
            }
            iframe {
                width: 400px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe frameborder="1"></iframe> <!--'1' for border on/ '0' for border off-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {

    document.write(selection[0]);

    var text =
        '<form action="http://localhost:8080/example" method="post" id="hlgt_form">' +
        '<input type="hidden" id = "hlgt" name = "hlgt" value= ""> ' +
        '</form>';

    document.write(text);

    document.getElementById('hlgt').value = selection[0];
    // it stores highlights into value of <input>

    document.getElementById('hlgt_form').submit();
});
```

**app.js** (run by node app.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});

app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`${req.body.name.hlgt}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your express app. You don't seem to be using the body-parser middleware to actually obtain the HTTP POST data in your request, and even if you did, you would reference that info as `req.body.hlgt`, without `.name`.

Try something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});

app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`${req.body.hlgt}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write only these two lines

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"5MB"}));
```